# Factorial iteration java

Tags: java, iteration, factorial

poCould anyone explain this piece of code to me?? Its a power function using iteration

```
  public static int iterate(int a, int n) 
{
    int i ;
    int result = 1 ;

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        result = result*a ;              
    }
    return result ;

}
```

Comment: result = result * a --> a should be i and i sould start from 1  in the for loop.

Comment: I would step through the code using a debugger to see what each line of code does.  Knowing how to use the debugger in your IDE is a basic skill.

Comment: Why is there "factorial" in the question title, but "power function" in the question body? If you mean factorial, your code is wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to know the definition of factorial:

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2*1 = 2
3! = 3*2*1 = 6
4! = 4*3*2*1 = 24
n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1
```

See the pattern?

1. Start with result = 1
2. Loop and multiply by index
3. Return result

What you posted looks more like `a^n = a*a*a...*a` to me, not factorial.